# RewriteRule doesn't with contact and about words

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

So basically some words don't work with RewriteRule, this is driving me crazy.

This is my htaccess code which doesn't work:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^contact/?$ index.php?page=contact [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^about/?$ index.php?page=about [NC,L]
```

Using this I get this error: "The requested URL /about was not found on this server."

If I change "contact" and "about" and put any other words, than it works fine:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^contactme/?$ index.php?page=contact [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^aboutme/?$ index.php?page=about [NC,L]
```

This works fine, but I want to use simple contact and about.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You do not have `contact` and `about` directory or file ?

Comment: I have contact.php and about.php

Comment: Looks like it's matching on those files then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use that:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -MultiViews
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ index.php?page=contact [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^about/?$ index.php?page=about [NC,L]
```

The effect of MultiViews is as follows: if the server receives a request for /some/dir/foo, if /some/dir has MultiViews enabled, and /some/dir/foo does not exist, then the server reads the directory looking for files named foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then chooses the best match to the client's requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation I removed MultiViews  from apache2.conf and works

Comment: Of course you can do that, if other part of the server/site do not depend on this option. But that would not normally be the case.